# WiFi frequently disconnected only on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, wireless, network-manager, disconnect

I am facing this problem for a while, and I tried many solutions that have been provided online like:

- set wifi.powersave to equal 2.
- disable the ipv6.
- access this file: `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<wifiname>.nmconnection`
  and add `auth-alg=open` under the wifi security section.
  and really many more.

This is the output for `uname -r`: **5.15.0-72-generic
**

This is the output for `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 81)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Please help me if you can, I've attached the output of `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCAWI.png).

```
Jun 01 18:57:16 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <warn>  [1685635036.2201] sup-iface[0x55fd0c4e44e0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jun 01 18:57:16 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635036.2504] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun 01 18:57:16 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635036.2506] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun 01 18:57:16 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635036.3235] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 01 18:57:16 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635036.3236] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.6599] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.6601] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.6928] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.6930] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.7131] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jun 01 18:57:19 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635039.7132] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Jun 01 18:57:20 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635040.6916] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jun 01 18:57:20 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635040.6918] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Jun 01 18:57:20 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635040.7379] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 01 18:57:20 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635040.7431] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 01 18:57:25 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <warn>  [1685635045.0899] sup-iface[0x55fd0c4e44e0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jun 01 18:57:25 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635045.1066] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun 01 18:57:25 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635045.1067] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jun 01 18:57:25 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635045.1943] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 01 18:57:25 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635045.1943] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5328] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5329] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5507] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5508] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5544] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jun 01 18:57:28 ubuntu64 NetworkManager[40294]: <info>  [1685635048.5545] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
```

Comment: please attach text ouptut as text, rather than as images. It makes it much easier to read and use for the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: if you look up the reason code it's giving you (`reason -4`) you will find it refers to "Disassociated due to inactivity" which means your session timed out.

Comment: also please paste output of `uname -r` and `lspci`

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will paste the output in post due to maximum number of char.